# How to write to a socket file descriptor without using ``connect()``?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to write through a socket using its descriptor. I have used `bind()` to bind the socket to the address I want. Whenever I'm using `sendto()` everything is OK. But whenever I'm using `write()` (or `send()`) I'll face `Destination address required`(errno 89).

What I'm trying to do is to write through the socket using `iovec`. In this case we don't have any alternative for `writev()` to get destination address. As I don't want to connect every single time, I was wondering whether I can do it without having to use `connect()` or `accept()` syscalls.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
int sock = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
char *hello = "chetori to"; 
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) 
{ 
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
    return -1; 
} 
int opt = 1; 
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

string interface_name = "lo";
ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface_name.c_str());
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&ifr), sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
    throw exception();  // Imaginary exception

memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

string interface_address = "127.0.0.1";
if (inet_aton(interface_address.c_str(), &serv_addr.sin_addr) == 0)
    throw exception();  // Imaginary exception

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (bind(sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    throw exception();  // Imaginary exception
    
char f[1024] = "Hello there";
char sec[1024] = "How are you";
char th[1024] = "I'm fine";
char fh[1024] = "Bye bye";
struct iovec bufs[] = {
    { .iov_base = f, .iov_len = sizeof(f) },
    { .iov_base = sec, .iov_len = sizeof(sec) },
    { .iov_base = th, .iov_len = sizeof(th) },
    { .iov_base = fh, .iov_len = sizeof(fh) },
};
int iovcnt = sizeof(bufs) / sizeof(struct iovec);
writev(sock, bufs, iovcnt);
```

Note that Interface name and IP address have no problem and are correct.

Comment: The `bind` call binds the socket to a *local* end-point. To send a datagram you need to provide the *remote* end-point. Where should the message be sent to? The `send` and `write` functions doesn't have any capabilities to provide that remote end-point, while `sendto` do.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't tag multiple languages in your questions. If you have written a program in one language, then tag only that language. Case in point: The code you show is not C, it have statements and types that are only valid in C++.

Comment: Well, a destination address has to be specified in some form or fashion, and `connect`() is how it's done. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to have some kind of alternative to `connect`() here that does exactly the same thing, what would be the point of having `connect()`, then? Nope, this is fairly cut and dry, there are no alternatives system calls.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It made me wonder what does ``bind()`` do? (It's my own question independent of this asked question)